# Attachment Problem......?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

hi i am using built in attachment in a list  i have created an textbox and a button and i would like to show the url of the attachment in the textbox `TextBox1.Text = customer["Attachments"].ToString();`

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList customerList = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
        if (customerList != null)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query =
                string.Format(
                    "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>",
                    prod);
            query.RowLimit = 10;

            SPListItemCollection items = customerList.GetItems(query);
```

when writing like this i get in the textbox true... whats the problem???[image]

this solved my problem...

```
 SPAttachmentCollection collAttachments = customer.Attachments;

                if (collAttachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < collAttachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(collAttachments[i]);
                    }
                }

                customer.Update();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, `customer["Attachments"]` will return for you an `SPAttachmentCollection`, so converting that to string is probably not what you want.

Please try something like this to obtain the URL of each attached file from the attachment collection of a list item.

```
SPAttachmentCollection collAttachments = oListItem.Attachments;

for (int i=0; i<collAttachments.Count; i++)
{
   TextBox1.Text += collAttachments[i];
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Cheers!

Comment: hi yes thanks , but i get the problem then every time i press make changes is makes duplicates for me..

Comment: Ok, the one above was just a sample. If you want it translated to your particular case, I think it should be something like this: get rid of the for cycle. Just use: `TextBox1.Text = collAttachments[0];` Of course, checking first `if (collAttachments.Count > 0)` wouldn't hurt :)